# How to configure WebPack only for SASS to CSS

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm very noob with WebPack

I try to find the simplest configuration code for using it to tranform a sass file to a css file

Someone could give me a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get `sass-loader`

Then add this in your config

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

After that you can require your scss files like this

```
require("./styles.scss").
```